# Show multiple items in a CardView . Something like a ListView or GridView

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

[image: Sample Card View]

I am retrieving data form FireStore Database in a array form. I want to show that values in a CardView. First thing that I tried to create some fixed Views to show items. But the challenge is that I don't know the count of that items. It may be 2 or be 12 but not more than that. Than I tried to set a ListView in CardView but I don't able to get desired results. So can you suggest me how I can do that.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card3_details_activity"
        android:layout_below="@id/card2_details_activity"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



           <ListView
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/list_facilities_details"
                android:fontFamily="@font/spinnaker"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"


                />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: So the cardview is of fixed size? What happens when the list exceeds the size of cardview? Does it scroll?

Comment: No. It doesn't scroll properly. But I want to show the card of fixed size like sample image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` inside your `CardView`. Sample XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now programmatically set fixed size on your `RecyclerView` to true, set the LayoutManager and create a custom RecyclerView.Adapter to fill the RecyclerView's rows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, dataSet);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For your case, there is now a library called [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) that includes a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and much more. Use it to populate your RecyclerView.

Comment: Ok I will try that to do with Recycler View.Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the answer helped you resolve the question, consider accepting it.